# link to a different admin object in an admin template

Tags: django, django-admin

I don't want to get my hands dirty with js. I have two models, `car` and `model`.

How can I manually add a link from a car to it's model in a custom admin template?

I can do:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:appname_carmodels_changelist' %}">access changelist</a>
```

But how would I access the model with pk=42? I tried:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:appname_carmodels_change' 42 %}">access changeform</a>
```

But I end up with a `NoReverseMatch at /admin/appname/carmodel/.../change/`. Is this possible? Or do I have to use some `extra_context` that can carry the reverse function?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html


@admin.register(YourAPP)
class AdminCustome(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'link_to_other_obj',)

    def link_to_other_obj(self, obj):
        # foreign key is your other object(for example carmodel)
        related_obj = obj.foreign_key
        url = reverse('admin:appname_carmodels_change', args=[related_obj.id])
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, related_obj)

 link_to_other_obj.short_description = 'go_to_car_model_page'
```